# Ensure the same field status within 2 dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Hi I have this query where I want to check between this 2 dates all those device where between the 10 days have the status of v for all the days. I want the status to be v within the 10 days to be same status I dont want it to be either i, d,a and p but must be only v but here I get even if it appears to be only of the date.

```
SELECT Distinct sd.deviceID
 FROM tblStatusDetails sd
  JOIN   
 WHERE sd.status = 'v' 
   And sd.status != 'a' 
   And sd.status != 'i' 
   And sd.status != 'd' 
   And sd.status !='p' 
   And sd.dailyDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('".$mysqlBeginDate."', INTERVAL 10 DAY) And '".$mysqlBeginDate."'";
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry why is it downvote when some could understand and gave proper answer I think this is un fair settings

Comment: The hope is that you are encouraged to post better questions next time.

Comment: Surely but pls dont downvote my this question its given an answer I feel bad for Vasyl Moskalov he has answered n it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you need only devices which have only status 'v' during this 10 days? So, something like

```
select tblStatusDetails.deviceID from tblStatusDetails
where tblStatusDetails.status='v' and 
tblStatusDetails.dailyDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('".$mysqlBeginDate."', INTERVAL 10 DAY) And '".$mysqlBeginDate."'"
group by tblStatusDetails.deviceId having count(*)>10
```

Comment: yes exactly you understood me exactly. But what is this logic >10 cause this is more than 10.